# iOS Developer Sample app to start

Tags: ios, sample

I've just started with ios development. I've been playing with little code here and there. I thought I should make a small goal to achieve so that I gain some confidence and feel familiar with iOS environment.. I saw this app (see below) and wanted to make a clone (not to sell it). When you see the app and when you click "Tips" tab there you can see in navigation bar there are 2 buttons one is right arrow and one is left. When you click there it shows another Weight Loss Tip. I don't get it, how he is able to only change the text?

I'm not asking code but just an idea. Thanks!

Any help?

https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/jamies-weight-loss-tips/id589703338?mt=8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should have a look at UIPageViewController. Check out the links below to have an idea on how to implement it.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/PageViewControllers.html

http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

by making a method that  responses on the touch and the sets the text for the linked outlet-referneses

for more info take a look at this tutorial:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_actions_and_outlets.htm

Answer (score 0):

For change views with animation you can use those methods:

```
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
[UIView transitionFromView:(UIView *) toView:(UIView *) duration:(NSTimeInterval) options:(UIViewAnimationOptions) completion:^(BOOL finished) {

}];

[UIView transitionWithView:(UIView *) duration:(NSTimeInterval) options:(UIViewAnimationOptions) animations:^{

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

}];
```